# View specific JavaScript code reuse in EmberJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Supposing I have two different views which contain the same view logic when the view in rendered.

I put my logic in the didInsertElement callback twice.

Are there any best practices in EmberJS to avoid view logic code duplication?

Looking forward to hearing your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with inheritance.

That being said, this could be your solution:

```
App.MyBaseView = Ember.View.extend({

    onDidInsert: function(){
        // shared logic
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});

App.FirstSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({

    onDidInsert: function(){
        // this views specific logic
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});

App.SecondSpecificView = App.MyBaseView.extend({

    onDidInsert: function(){
        // this views specific logic
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

You would create a basic view which implements the base logic, and extend said view with specific logic.

Comment: What is the purpose of using .on('didInsertElement')? What is the difference if we just use 'didInsertElement' instead of onDidInsert?